# HAProxy domain to backend with path?

Tags: haproxy

Short situation description:

- HAProxy running on 10.0.0.100
- Domain cloud.example.net -> 10.0.0.100
- HAProxy needs to route cloud.example.net to 10.0.0.201/owncloud/

Is it possible to make the server use a backend with path?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]! Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]! Right now, you are way too broad!

Comment: That question did not answer mine, but it did get me in the right direction! Its working after some changes "reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /(.*)     \1\ /owncloud/\2" Thanks @HolgerJust. Sorry for unclear question above.